# Python requests proxy Failed to Parse error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a website with a proxy. But when I use the code below I get an error. I tried changing http to https. I tried different proxies. But non of them solved my issue.

```
import requests

proxies = {"http": "http://91.93.135.113:8080"}

requests.get("http://ifconfig.me/ip", proxies=proxies).content
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 305, in get_connection
    proxy_url = parse_url(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\url.py", line 392, in parse_url
    return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: http://46.197.209.217:3128

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 414, in send
    raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://46.197.209.217:3128
```

Comment: The errored proxy doesn't correspond to the code you're giving.  Where does the 46.197.209.217:3128 come from?

Comment: I got the proxy from proxydb.com. What is the output on your device?

Comment: What happens if you run your code as is; that is, using your original proxy as stated in the code?"

Comment: Yes I'm using the same proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Burp Proxy!
I just change Burp Options on Proxy Label to bind all interfaces (0.0.0.0) and it works with your code.